Updating Authorization Filter to .NET Core
I have an old web service built in standard .NET in C#.  It's main job is SMTP, but it does some Authentication and Authorization before hand.  It uses an AuthorizationFilter that I'm not familiar with, where it gets the HTTPRequest that comes in, gets the principal user of that request, and then checks it's AD groups before returning an IsAuthorized if they are on the list of user groups accepted.
I 'see' how this is done here, but now I'm trying to figure out what the .NET Core analog is to this.  I know I can set Authorizations on a controller, but I don't know what to use to do the filtering.  I assume I capture the HTTPContext, get the user, check it against the groups that it has, and either succeeds or fails it...but I'm assuming that .NET Core has a more 'built in' way of doing that.  What would be the best for taking an HTTP Request and checking Authorization based on the requesting users AD groups?

According to your description, I suggest you could follow this article to create a new Authorization handlers for a new custom requirement which could set the AD group name to check it.
More details, you could refer to below codes:
AdGroupRequirement:
public class AdGroupRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
    public AdGroupRequirement(string groupName)
    {
        GroupName = groupName;
    }

    public string GroupName { get; }
}

Handler class:
public class AdGroupHandler : AuthorizationHandler<AdGroupRequirement>
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public AdGroupHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, AdGroupRequirement requirement)
    {
        var user = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User;

        if (user == null || !user.Identity.IsAuthenticated || !(user.Identity is WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity))
        {
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        // Check if the user is in the required AD group
   

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

Injected inside the program.cs:
builder.Services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("RequireAdGroup", policy =>
        policy.Requirements.Add(new AdGroupRequirement("YourADGroupName")));
});

Use it inside the controller:
[Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdGroup")]
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class EmployeeController : ControllerBase
{
    
}


I think this would be the right direction, but I'm constantly getting this error about Authentication.
No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found.

Never mind, figured it out.  Needed to put some Authentication in there to.  Works great for me now!  Thanks!
